# Plyer Camera on Android doesnt run

Tags: android, python, camera, kivy, buildozer

Im trying to code an apk using buildozer, plyer and kivy to capture a photo on an android device. Having a lot of trouble with the `take_picture()` method. Originally i was using `Camera().take_picture()` but after looking into the source code a little i decided to bypass Cameras multi platform ability and use `AndroidCamera()` class instead. My code is as follows(sorry for the bulk):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
#from kivy.facades.camera import Camera
from plyer.platforms.android.camera import AndroidCamera
import datetime

class CameraApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.label =Label(text='Camera Test')
        return self.label

    def on_start(self):
        self.take_shot()

    def take_shot(self):
        IMAGEPATH='DCIM/Camera'
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M')
        self.file_name='{0}/IMG_{1}.jpg'.format(IMAGEPATH,time)
        try:
            AndroidCamera().take_picture(filename=self.file_name,
                                         on_complete=self.complete_callback())    
            self.label.text=(self.file_name +str('\nCaptured'))
        except:
            self.label.text=(self.file_name+str('\nFailed to Capture'))

    def complete_callback(self):
        return False

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass


if __name__=='__main__':
    CameraApp().run()
```

When i run ***this code*** on android the app crashes, but when i use the standard `Camera().take_picture()` the code catches the exception but still does not take a photo.

My question is, can anybody see where ive gone wrong?

Incidently i get this traceback on the usb debug, though its meaning i cannot work out:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 91, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 973, in cmd_logcat
    show_output=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 314, in cmd
    stdout.write(chunk.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 107: invalid start byte
```